# Enabling both a PHP parser and an Include statement

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, include, shtml

I have an existing SHTML page with a few INCLUDE statements for menu's.  This has worked well.  To this point, my .htaccess file has looked like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

And my Include statement looked like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="menu_primary.shtml" -->
```

I have a new need to add some PHP code to the main page.  The PHP code queries a Mysql database to return a single row.  If the row exists in the database, I want to show it on the SHTML page.  If the row does not exist, do nothing.  Here's the PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT notice from notification where page = 'home'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Message is: " . $row["notice"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

When I implemented this PHP code, the page seemed to interpret everything after the Greater Than symbol as text.  When I posted that problem, someone on this forum suggested altering the .htaccess file to include a PHP parser.  For a while. I altered my .htaccess file to look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|shtm|shtml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
```

However when I do that, the PHP code works fine and I display the data from the database on the SHTML page, but the #Include statements no longer work.  How can I enable both the PHP and #Include code together in the same SHTML page?  Thanks very much for looking at this.

Comment: Is it a requirement to have the HTML includes? PHP can include pages aswell.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script you can invoke the [virtual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php) function to work with your SSI

```
<?php
virtual('menu_primary.shtml');
```

There's a very old page that talks about this in more detail
http://www.zytrax.com/tech/php/php_ssi.htm

Comment: Hi Mahavity,  Thanks for the answer.  What ended up working for me was slightly different from what you provided.  Inside of my SHTML file I used: <?php include("menu_primary.shtml");
?>